# How to limit CPU consumtion of a process group with standard GNU/Linux tools?

Tags: linux, bash, cpu, process, time

I have a bunch of processes of the same name - they take up 100% of my CPU time, I want this to be no more than 50%.

How can I do this without installing any extra software?

Comment: Do you mean to limit each process to 50% of a CPU, or do you want to limit the *aggregate* CPU usage of all those processes?  The answer may well depend on that distinction.

Comment: Have you considered setting process affinity for them to 50% of cores?

Comment: Most of the time I see questions like this, I wonder if the OP wouldn't be better of using [`nice`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nice.2.html)...

Answer (score 4):

For a kernel-level mechanism for this, you need to read up on Linux [Control Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups).  This is an area still in active development, so you'll need to ensure that what you read is consistent with the kernel you have (or are willing to install).

Although you said not to install anything additional, you might consider installing `cgred` to automate moving processes with matching names to your CPU cgroup.  On Debian, this in in the `cgroup-bin` package.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so with bash shell, sleep, pgrep, and pkill commands using STOP and CONT signals.

The following one-liner will make the processes use maximum of 50% of total availabile CPU time. It's going to run for each 100 miliseconds, then it'll be stopped for another 100 milliseconds.

```
while [ True ]; do pkill -STOP processname; sleep 0.1s; pkill -CONT processname; sleep 0.1s; done
```

Here's the same code split into multiple lines for readability:

```
while [ True ]
     do pkill -STOP processname
     sleep 0.1s
     pkill -CONT processname
     sleep 0.1s
done
```

No mater how much processes exist maching the processname pattern, they can't excess 50% of CPU usage, becasue they are all stopped and continued at the same time - which means they need to share the avaiabile CPU time between them, when they are active. This ensures the limit is met.

There is a program called cpulimit that does roughly the same thing.

Comment: The downside to this is that it plays poorly in the idle state, because you are now waking 10 times a second whether it's necessary or not.  This will diminish the benefits of NOHZ in your kernel.  Of course, if your system is never idle, that won't be an issue for you, but it is worth at least mentioning.  See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: Processes sometimes react weirdly if stopped and continued.  Especially if they are terminal-interactive.  So this might not work with every program, and a corresponding warning should be included in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Without installing any extra software you have `nice`. The value range is from *-20* to *19*.

```
nice -20 some_command
```

gives `some_command`the *highest priority*, and

```
nice 19 some_command
```

gives `some_command`the *lowest priority*.

Comment: If you *nice* a bunch of processes, they won't get 50% of CPU time when something else wants to use 100% of the CPU.

Comment: … And if nothing else is using CPU time, they still are gobbling up all the 100%.  But mentioning `nice` in this context surely is worth the effort.

Comment: Why would anyone *want* a process to get 50% of CPU in the first place? I cannot think of any non-esoteric scenario where this would make more sense than using nice.

Comment: Doesn't seem like an esoteric scenario to me as I encounter it frequently.  Users wanting to run larger processing tasks, but not allow them to knock down the rest of the machine at the same time.  A % of CPU limit would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

as written above could be  used as a script to assist  OOM-killer Or prevent its use as well

say  when cpu overall hits   75% for x mins   run pkill.sh

```
 ../scripts/boottime/OOMkiller.sh

while [ true] ; 
    do  inxi -tcm5 > ~/cpu.log 
    sleep 0.5s 
    inxi -tcm5 >> ~/cpu/log | diff -m > ~/offender.log
done

for i in offender.log ;
    do ./scripts/pkill.sh
done

 ../scripts/pkill.sh
while [true] 
    do pgrep $(i) -STOP $PID
    pkill -STOP $PID
    sleep 0.5s 
    pkill -CONT $PID
done
```